# Is it possible to recording Agora SDK Video Call?

Tags: video, call, recording, agora.io

I am developing an application with Video call. Which SDK will support all of the features like video calling and recording(Which should store into our server) for Android, IOS and Web

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to record the Agora Video session. Agora provides implementations to set up on-premise recording (https://docs.agora.io/en/Recording/product_recording?platform=All%20Platforms) and cloud-based recording for this purpose. It uses the Agora Recording SDK and also provides a Rest API interface to get everything set up out the box. Here is the link to the repo: https://github.com/AgoraIO/Basic-Recording

The video recording service joins the channel in which the session is going on. You have to provide the AppID and channelName and start the recorder. The video and audio files are generated separately and you need to combine them with a script provided.